# Python : Manga parsing return empty file

Tags: python

i want to parse images from a "certain" manga and chapter. here's my code:

```
import requests, bs4, os, urllib.request

try:
    url = "http://manganelo.com/chapter/read_one_punch_man_manga_online_free3/chapter_136"
    res = requests.get(url)
    print("[+] Asking a request to " + url)

    # slice the url so it only contains the name and chapter
    name = url[34:].replace("/", "_")
    os.mkdir(name)
    print("[+] Making '{}' directory".format(name))
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name))

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    for img in soup.findAll("img"):
        manga_url = img.get("src")
        manga_name = img.get("alt") + ".jpg"

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(manga_url, manga_name)
        print("[+] Downloading: " + manga_name)

except Exception as e:
    print("[-] Error: " + str(e))
```

it works fine BUT only for a specific chapter, let's say i put chapter 130, when i try to run the code it returns blank file but if i put chapter 136 or others it works fine. How can this happen?

Comment: No repro. Works with chapter 130 on my machine. (Well, both chapter 130 and 136 throw an error in the end, but the first few images work.)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `urllib.request.urlretrieve(manga_url, manga_name)`

with :

```
    r = requests.get(manga_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(manga_name, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Actually Remote server is apparently checking the user agent header and rejecting requests from Python's urllib.

On the other hand you can use :

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'whatever')
opener.retrieve(manga_url, manga_name)
```

This works for me

Hope this helps